# XSLT variable for use as temporary document and to output on xml format

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, output, saxon

I want to create temporary documents so I can reorder them and also to clarify a bushy programming.
I do not understand the behavior that I observe: if I execute without encapsulating my code in a variable it executes as I wish it but as soon as I integrate it to a variable it derails.

#### varnovar.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
saxonb-xslt -ext:on -xsl:varnovar.xsl -it:'template-novar' && {
    cat novar.xml
}
printf "\n"
saxonb-xslt -ext:on -xsl:varnovar.xsl -it:'template-var' && {
    cat var.xml
}
printf "\n"
exit
```

#### varnovar.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- I want a XML output !!! Help !!! Help !!! Help !!! -->
    <xsl:output name="format-tempxml" method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!-- without a variable -->
    <xsl:template name="template-novar">
        <xsl:result-document href="novar.xml" format="format-tempxml">
            <!-- xsl:variable name="variable-node" as="node()" -->
                <xsl:element name="root"><xsl:value-of select="'route'" /></xsl:element>
            <!-- /xsl:variable -->
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($variable-node/root, '&#xa;')" />
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- with a variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="variable-node">
        <xsl:element name="root"><xsl:value-of select="'route'" /></xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template name="template-var">
        <xsl:result-document href="var.xml" format="format-tempxml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$variable-node" />
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($variable-node/root, '&#xa;')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>route
<root>route</root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>route
route
```

## Question

1. Why the resulting document is no longer XML when I go through a variable? (and how to correct this?)

### Other questions

2. Why the `xsl:output` element is ignored (`omit-xml-declaration` is ignored)
3. Why the `concat($variable-node/root, '&#xa;')` does not cause a variable not found condition in the `novar` template?

Merci à qui saura éclairer ma lanterne!

Answer (score 1):

As for your question about the variable, you have a global `xsl:variable name="variable-node"` which is in scope for any template you call.

As for the "missing" XML, you do `<xsl:apply-templates select="$variable-node" />` but have no templates set up so the built-in templates are used which only copy text nodes through. I am not sure you really use an XSLT 3 processor as your version `3.0` suggest but if you do you can add `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shadow-copy"/>` to have a different behaviour which copies every node through, with an XSLT 2 processor you would need to add the identity transformation template.

As for the XML declaration, you have no unnamed `xsl:output` for the primary result set up so the default values are used.

Comment: Thank you. For the scope of the variable, I slept, excuse me!

Comment: For xsl:output I specified the attribute format="name of the output element" so I still do not understand. For the XSLT 3 processor, I use saxon HE and it seems do not support 3.0 and ignore "<xsl:mode on-no-match="shadow-copy"/>". For the most important, "missing XML, I do not understand " identity transformation template" here.

Comment: If you use Saxon 9 HE then make sure you use 9.8 HE if you want to use XSLT 3 and `xsl:mode`. As for the `xsl:output`, for the main output you need an unamed `xsl:output` (no `name` attribute) or you need to make sure your entry template uses `xsl:result-document`. And you might make your life easier and our life easier to understand the output if you don't mix shell scripting with XSLT, I think that is part of the current problem, the results you create with `xsl:result-document` don't have an XML declaration, but your shell script outputs them together with the direct output of Saxon.

Comment: The XML declarations came from  <xsl:value-of select="concat($variable-node/root, '&#xa;')" /> ! You were right!

Comment: Unfortunately Debian only allows to go to the Saxon HE 9.7 in the unstable repo, but I will monitor that.
I understand now your last remark: Thank You, the problem is understood.

Answer (score 1):

This architecture would suit what I want to do.
Many thanks to Mr Honnen and Mr Kay.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="variable-node">
        <root>route
            <child>D55
                <position>2</position>
            </child>
            <child>T40
                <position>1</position>
            </child>
        </root>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="template-var">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$variable-node" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:result-document href="var.xml">
            <root><xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <xsl:for-each select="child">
                <xsl:sort select="position"/>
                <child><xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                <position><xsl:value-of select="position" /></position>
                </child>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </root>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### result

```
<root>route
            <child>T40
                <position>1</position>
   </child>
   <child>D55
                <position>2</position>
   </child>
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but I receive a "Can't convert #RTREEFRAG to NodeList"

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of points to make here.

Firstly, you aren't showing your whole output. When you run with the template-novar entry point, there are two outputs: the principal output (written by default to the console) which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>route
```

and a secondary output (written to novar.xml) which is:

```
<root>route</root>
```

When you run with the template-var entry point, the principal output is again:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>route
```

and the secondary output (written to var.xml) is:

```
route
```

So the answers to your questions are:

> 1. Why the resulting document is no longer XML when I go through a variable? (and how to correct this?)

Well, actually var.xml is XML, but it is an XML document containing only a single text node. The variable contains an element named `<root>`, you apply-templates to this element, but there is no matching template rule, so the built-in template rule kicks in, and this copies only the text nodes.

> 2. Why the xsl:output element is ignored (omit-xml-declaration is ignored)

It isn't ignored. This output declaration is used for the secondary result documents but not for the principal result (which uses the unnamed output declaration). Your secondary result documents have no XML declaration.

> 3. Why the concat($variable-node/root, '
>    ')  does not cause a variable not found condition in the novar template?

Because global variables in XSLT are visible everywhere, even before they are declared.

Finally, in a comment on Martin's answer, you say:

> Unfortunately Debian only allows to go to the Saxon HE 9.7 in the unstable repo

It might be that Debian makes a particular version of Saxon HE available "out of the box", but I would be very surprised if it prevents you installing any version of Saxon that you choose by downloading it from Sourceforge or from www.saxonica.com.

Comment: Thank you, all your answers are clear to me except the first one.
It is not a text file that I want to create.
If I want to use a temporary tree I can only do it with a variable. From this temporary tree I have the ambition to sort it out and process it to finally output a SVG file, to tell you everything.
When, where, how, can I specify a "matching template rule" in my "apply-template" to output an true XML file, not an XML-text file?

Comment: Just add `<xsl:template match="root">(instructions here)</xsl:template>` as a child of xsl:stylesheet.

Comment: Following this last tip a quick test validates an architecture that suits me. Perfect!